# Max. number of visibile connection between polygons

Tags: combinations, polygons

I have one question regarding the connectivity of polygons.

Given a set of N polygons, each with V number of vertices, [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU4Jy.png) what is the max. number of connections that it is possible to make between all the vertices of all polygons? I assume some lines do not have to be considered twice. Some vertices will not have visibility to other vertices and should not be considered, but at this stage I would also include them and assume that they are connected.

Thanks.

Comment: By visibility, do you mean that the line between them should not intersect the interior of any of the polygons? The polygons could have one very long side so that all the vertices are visible from one direction. Then you could arrange the polygons to face each other in a circle so that every vertex is visible from every vertex of every other polygon. Therefore the visibility requirement does not necessarily reduce the maximum possible number of connections.

Comment: Please, read the tag descriptions. The question it's not about what is called "connections" in Mathematics. The tag combinatory logic is also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There are $NV$ vertices. Assuming that we are not considering connecting two vertices of the same polygon, each vertex can connect with $(N-1)V$ other vertices. So there are $NV\cdot(N-1)V=N(N-1)V^2$ directed edges (i.e. arrows) from one vertex to another, or $\frac12 N(N-1)V^2$ bidirectional connections.